# Calabash Android test procedure got very slow

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

I been using calabash-android for long time with real device, but never had this kind of slow testing procedure.I mean it used to go really in seconds to test my scenarios, but now it takes more than 1 minute .. It is the same laptop, only difference I tested on 15.04 Ubuntu before. Now I'm on

> Ubuntu 14.04.03LTS 64bit

... **Is it library missing or update to be made? or is Calabash got slower. Have no idea why its doing this**...

please can u suggest how to get my speed back?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to mark the question *solved*, then accept one of the answers.

Comment: Hmm sorry I am new here, I asked my own question didn't know i should put check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found out that Ruby version is old and reason cause installing Ruby through `sudo` new version was wrong way, cause it's not setting latest version to default. So I had to install `RVM` `Ruby Version Manager` and install latest `ruby` and set latest ruby version `--default` and re-install my `Calabash-Android`.

Answer (score 0):

We've actually recently made speed improvements to the queries, so the framework itself shouldn't be the cause of any new slowness. Which version are you using? Should be 0.6.0.

If you're saying you've downgraded your OS from 15.04 to 14.04, that would probably be my first guess. Is there any difference in log output from before if you run with `-v` for verbose?

Comment: hmm, well i did installed latest version of course but could this be SDK? i mean.. I was thinking its slow because communication between my device adb and calabash?

Comment: I did not downgrade, i re-installed it... May i know what lib it needs to work fast? or anything.. not sure what are the difference between 15.04 and 14.04.03